# subfigures don't show (a) and (b)

Tags: captions, subfloats

I want to insert to graphs into a paper. I want to make these two graphs arranged like the top 2 graphs in the following pic

[image: example]

however, using the following source, I can't see `(a)` and `(b)`
what are potential problems? thanks!

the source codes are with a [`IEEEtran.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls)

```
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

    \ifCLASSINFOpdf
       \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
       \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.eps}
    \else
       \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
       \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
    \fi


    \usepackage{lscape}
    %\usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{document}

    \title{0000}

    \author{\IEEEauthorblockN{00000}}

    \maketitle
    \end{abstract}

    \IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

    \section{0000}

      \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{pic/loop.png}
          \caption{First}
          \label{subfig-1:dummy}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{pic/twopath.png}
          \caption{Second}
          \label{subfig-2:dummy}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Dummy figure}
        \label{fig:dummy}
      \end{figure}

    \begin{thebibliography}{1}

    \end{thebibliography}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: The captions have to go into each `subfigure` environment.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig how? and how to deal with the labels? thanks

Comment: @misteryes Please, make a complete example document with the necessary packages, starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. However, your code seems to mean you are using the obsolete `subfigure` package (and in a wrong way). Note that Thorsten's solution uses `subcaption`, instead.

Comment: @egreg: For me the `subfigure` environments indicate that the OP uses already »[subcaption](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)«. The »[subfigure](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure)« package would need the `\subfigure` command.

Comment: I have updated the source code

Comment: Your example does not compile.

Comment: have you downloaded the `IEEEtran.cls` ?

Comment: @ThorstenDonig If you noticed, in the previous code, there was no argument to `\begin{subfigure}`, which would make `subcaption` balk; I used that code loading `subfigure` and it gave a result similar to the image uploaded by mysteries.

Comment: @misteryes: I don't need to download the class. It's installed on my system. Your example does not compile. Please fix the error first.

Comment: @Thorsten Donig  how to do that? thanks

Comment: @misteryes: By following the instructions for building a *proper* [minimal example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) as already requested earlier.

Answer (score 5):

Your error was to use the `subfigure` package with a wrong syntax; but the `subfigure` has been obsolete for several years and its author released a successor package, `subfig`, in 1999.

You have two alternatives. The first is using the more modern `subcaption` package; here's an example based on your sample code.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for this example, remove it
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\title{0000}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{00000}}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
X
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{0000}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic/loop.png}
\caption{First}
\label{subfig-1:dummy}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\columnwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic/twopath.png}
  \caption{Second}
  \label{subfig-2:dummy}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Dummy figure}
\label{fig:dummy}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

One important point to note: you can use `\columnwidth` to set the width of the subfigures and `\linewidth` in the argument to `\includegraphics` for using the whole reserved space. Or, for bigger pictures, use `\textwidth` but in the enclosing `figure*` environment, that will make a float as wide as the two columns.

[image]

The second possibility is with `subfig`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for this example, remove it
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\title{0000}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{00000}}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
X
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{0000}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\subfloat[title1]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{pic/loop.png}\label{fig:loop}}\hfill
\subfloat[title2]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{pic/twopath.png}\label{fig:twopath}}
\caption{packet structure}
\label{fig:routing}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The difference is that you don't have to specify a width for the subfloats like with `subcaption`. The syntax is quite different, as you can see. The output is just the same as before.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put the captions into each of the `subfigure` environments to get the correct numbering for the sub-figures.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{First}
      \label{subfig-1:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{Second}
      \label{subfig-2:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Dummy figure}
    \label{fig:dummy}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image files are available with »[mwe](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe)« package installed on your system.

---

[image]

---

**Update**

Now that the used is class known, the following approach should help.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % drop the `demo` option in actual document
\usepackage[belowskip=3pt]{subcaption}

\title{Document title}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

  \section{Foo}

  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{pic/loop.png}
      \caption{First}
      \label{subfig-1:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{pic/twopath.png}
      \caption{Second}
      \label{subfig-2:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Dummy figure}
    \label{fig:dummy}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I added caption before, pls see the update, but the result is this: http://s22.postimg.org/dnz0h4l0h/cap.png

Comment: @misteryes: Please take a look at the update I added to my initial answer. It uses the »[IEEEtran](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran)« class with your settings.

Comment: I'm using texstudio 2.3. I tried your source codes, the result is still as s22.postimg.org/dnz0h4l0h/cap.png. It prompts that there is no `subcaption.sty`. I downloaded a `subcaption.sty` and put it in the same folder as the .tex file. But the compilation incurs a lot of errors.

Comment: @misteryes: Install or update the »[caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)« bundle by the package manager of your TeX distribution. The »[subcaption](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)« package is part of that bundle.

Comment: how to install or update caption in texstudio? thanks

Comment: @misteryes: TeXstudio is only the editor. Your TeX system needs the update. But until now you didn't tell details. Perhaps the answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132927) can help.