# File `subcaption.sty' not found. in texstudio

Tags: texstudio, subcaption

I'm using texstudio on linux for writing paper.

the version is: 
    TeXstudio 2.3 (SVN ??)
    Using Qt Version 4.8.4, compiled with Qt 4.8.0
    Copyright (c) (original TexMaker) 2004-2010 by Pascal Brachet
    TeXstudio: Benito van der Zander, Jan Sundermeyer, Daniel Braun

I want to compile the following source code(the source codes are with a [`IEEEtran.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls) ), but it shows : File `subcaption.sty' not found. in texstudio. then I downloaded subcaption.sty and put it in the same folder as the .tex file, there are even more errors. how to deal with this?

My OS is fedora 16, my used version is `This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6) (format=pdflatex 2012.2.27) 12 SEP 2013 13:25`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for this example, remove it
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\title{0000}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{00000}}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
X
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{0000}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic/loop.png}
\caption{First}
\label{subfig-1:dummy}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\columnwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic/twopath.png}
  \caption{Second}
  \label{subfig-2:dummy}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Dummy figure}
\label{fig:dummy}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your TeX distribution is outdated.  Compare please my version

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
```

with your version

```
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3
```

and check the bold parts.

Please look which of these questions helps you to update your system:

- [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)
- [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)
- [How to install LaTeX on Fedora 15 ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/how-to-install-latex-on-fedora-15)

After updating your MWE will compile, but take a look to the resulting warning: the document class `IEEEtran` is not supported by the packages `caption` and `subcaption`. Check the resulting PDF file.

Comment: thanks! if `IEEEtran` is not supported by the packages caption and subcaption, what can I do?

Comment: Besides, I still don't know what is my TeX distribution, is it TexLive? how to check?

Comment: I'm user1944267. what do you mean by saying "have you to use this documentclass? " I want to use IEEEtran for a IEEE paper. I want to use caption because of this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/subfigures-dont-show-a-and-b

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue an old version on a shared user system where I couldn't install new packages.

I downloaded the [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package from CTAN and followed the wiki's [manual installation instructions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages#Manual_installation).

Answer (score 1):

`subcaption.sty` is contained in the [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, so this worked for me:

```
tlmgr install caption
```